# dao recordset updating the wrong record

Tags: recordset, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to have a form usable for both creating a new record or updating another. Currently it is doing it through the value of a textbox (new or edit). The structure works fine, but for some reason, when it is performing the edit function, it is saving changes to the wrong record. For instance, if I am editing record 1027, when i submit it, it'll update record 1073. Its consistent, it'll always update the same, wrong record. Edit 1000, it'll update 1073; if i update 1081, it'll update 1073, and so on. Is there a way to specify which record it should be editing? yes, the record number is the primary key/id. Heres the code:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

 Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim strField As String
    Dim ID As Long
    Dim newID As Long

    strTable = "record_holdData"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strTable)

'button has 2 modes
If txtMode.Value = "NEW" Then

    With rs
        .AddNew
        .Fields("PO_no") = txtPONum
        .Fields("prodSupervisor") = cboProdSup
        .Fields("qaSupervisor") = cboQASup
        .Fields("labTech") = cboLabTech
        .Fields("flavor") = cboFlavor
        .Fields("lineNumber") = cboLineNumber
        .Fields("container") = cboContainer
        .Fields("package") = cboPackage
        .Fields("holdQty") = txtQty
        .Fields("productionDate") = txtProdDate
        .Fields("dateCode") = txtDatecode
        .Fields("component") = cboComponent
        .Fields("nonconformance") = cboDiscrepancy
        .Fields("foundDuring") = cboFoundAt
        .Fields("responsibility") = cboRespCode
        .Fields("comments") = txtDescription
        .Fields("rootCause") = txtRootCause
        .Fields("holdStatus") = 1
        .Fields("dateOpened") = Now()
        .Update
        .Bookmark = .LastModified
        newID = !ID
    End With

        MsgBox ("Hold information saved!")
        btnPrintTag.Enabled = True
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Holdtag", acViewPreview, , "[ID] = " & newID
        DoCmd.Close

ElseIf txtMode.Value = "EDIT" Then
    'do editing stuff
    With rs
        .Edit
        .Fields("PO_no") = txtPONum
        .Fields("prodSupervisor") = cboProdSup
        .Fields("qaSupervisor") = cboQASup
        .Fields("labTech") = cboLabTech
        .Fields("flavor") = cboFlavor
        .Fields("lineNumber") = cboLineNumber
        .Fields("container") = cboContainer
        .Fields("package") = cboPackage
        .Fields("holdQty") = txtQty
        .Fields("productionDate") = txtProdDate
        .Fields("dateCode") = txtDatecode
        .Fields("component") = cboComponent
        .Fields("nonconformance") = cboDiscrepancy
        .Fields("foundDuring") = cboFoundAt
        .Fields("responsibility") = cboRespCode
        .Fields("comments") = txtDescription
        .Fields("rootCause") = txtRootCause
        .Fields("lastEditDate") = Now()
        .Update
    End With

    MsgBox ("Information Updated")

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i caught it. Problem was I was basically redefining the recordset each time the subroutine was called. I changed the second block to the following:

```
ElseIf txtMode.Value = "EDIT" Then
    'do editing stuff
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM record_holdData WHERE ID=" & txtID)
    With rs
        .Edit
        .Fields("PO_no") = txtPONum
        .Fields("prodSupervisor") = cboProdSup
        .Fields("qaSupervisor") = cboQASup
        .Fields("labTech") = cboLabTech
        .Fields("flavor") = cboFlavor
        .Fields("lineNumber") = cboLineNumber
        .Fields("container") = cboContainer
        .Fields("package") = cboPackage
        .Fields("holdQty") = txtQty
        .Fields("productionDate") = txtProdDate
        .Fields("dateCode") = txtDatecode
        .Fields("component") = cboComponent
        .Fields("nonconformance") = cboDiscrepancy
        .Fields("foundDuring") = cboFoundAt
        .Fields("responsibility") = cboRespCode
        .Fields("comments") = txtDescription
        .Fields("rootCause") = txtRootCause
        .Fields("lastEditDate") = Now()
        .Update
    End With
```